# Comma in URL field

Tags: sharepoint-designer, xslt, list

I'm having some trouble with URL fields in my List. The problem is that SharePoint stores URLs in two parts, "Description" and "Url", but in SharePoint Designer I can only access the whole URL in the form of `<Url>, <Description>`. Splitting the string at ', ' is not complicated, but for some reason all Urls containing a ',' are escaped to ',, '.

So my url: http://example.com/myimage,cool.jpg
is rendered as: http://example.com/myimage,, cool.jpg, Description

Is there any elegant way to fix this (tried output escaping, but the ,, still remained) or do I have to go through some tedious xslt transformations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I got around the problem:
Used a similar XSLT function:
http://geekswithblogs.net/Erik/archive/2008/04/01/120915.aspx
and called it:

```
<xsl:variable name="imgEscapedTemp">
  <xsl:call-template name="string-replace-all">
    <xsl:with-param name="text" select="@Image" />
    <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="',,'" />
    <xsl:with-param name="by" select="'##'" />
  </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="imgEscaped">
  <xsl:call-template name="string-replace-all">
    <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-before($imgEscapedTemp, ', ')" />
    <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="'##'" />
    <xsl:with-param name="by" select="','" />
  </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:variable>

<img src="{$imgEscaped}" alt=myImage" />
```

Logic: replace ',,' with '##', substring before ', ' and then replace '##' with ','

Answer (score 0):

Tried using something like this?

```
 <xsl:value-of select="$MyUrlVal" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
```

Comment: Yep, didn't help: <img alt="myimage">
      <xsl:attribute name="src">
      <xsl:value-of select="@Myimage" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
      </xsl:attribute>
      </img>

Answer (score 0):

Use the xsl substring-before function, it isn't difficult.

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring-before(@URL, ', ')"/>
```

Comment: But when your value is literally `http://server/myimage,,cool.jpg` then that won't do much.

Comment: That's an input validation issue since that isn't a valid URL to begin with.  That should be addressed in a presave action perhaps.

Comment: I just tested the above with a URL with a comma in it and it does work properly.  It is looking for everything before comma space and returns that.  SO if it were input as http://example.com/myimage,cool.jpg with a description of Why would you do this, it renders as http://example.com/myimage,cool.jpg in my DVWP.

Comment: If I remember correctly, then the double commas were followed by a space and the file names contained multiple commas in different locations. Unfortunately, there's no way to run substring-before() on the last match. I'll check it in the morning.